# Does the boost library depend on the std C++ library?

Tags: c++, boost

We're needing to write small fast code on the windows platform and I know that boost in some instances has header only implementations.  These need to be small for a reason, so we've been careful not to use the std C++ libraries actually because of size.

My question is, does using boost asio or system also haul in the std C++ libraries under windows?

EDIT: Yes, small and fast.  I know parts of the std c++ library are very fast if not faster than C.  But, size is a factor for us as end users will download these on the fly and we dont want any major dependencies or huge downloads like pulling in MFC to use one function! We tend to use C++ like an extended version of C++.  Only the objects are used, no RTTI, no IO streams.

I guess my question boils down to:
Which parts of boost are likely to use the streams library?
Is ASIO going to bloat my code more than just using the win32 API directly?

Comment: Header only libraries (i.e. anything templated) tend to bloat app size, not shrink, due to implementations being inlined instead of shared. If small is your aim, you might be better off using C, instead of C++. Small & fast with C++ is difficult without writing a lot of custom code. Now, you might have some luck in release mode using whole program optimization on windows. It may be able to eliminate redundant code, but there's going to be a trade off between size & speed.

Comment: @Nathan: Just optimize for size instead of speed via your compilers options. It's not hard at all. If template instantiations still take up too much,  just change `T` to `void*` and do casts. (Trade safety and ease of use for size.) C++ to C isn't simply dependent on just templates.

Comment: How does use of the standard library result in large code size? I doubt anything you implement yourself that performs the same function is going to be any smaller (with the possible exception of `iostream`)

Comment: @GMan, I was making a generalization. I hate eliminating safety (which I know as soon as you introduce C, you've sort of already done). Honestly, I think the OP would be better off writing the code naturally and then profile to see where to improve speed. Even on todays least capable computers, I hardly see linking in the C++ standard lib as being a concern.

Comment: @Nathan: An untrue generalization. Making it *possible* for the compiler to inline doesn't usually cause code bloat. The compiler isn't stupid, and doesn't inline unless the payoff is worth it. The code bloat often associated with templates have a different reason

Comment: @jalf, you're correct, the compiler isn't stupid, however it only works at the compilation unit level. If you have a non-trivial application, for argument 200 compilation units that all utilize a vector of strings, do you seriously think the *compiler* can optimize the redundant instantiations away? Of course it cannot. Only a linker can, unless the compiler defers references of templates until later, and I know of no compiler/linker combination that does so. If the bloat from templates has a different reason, care to name one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, Boost just provides a layer of abstraction. It has to use the C++ STL library at some point. If you don't believe me, just check the code.

Comment: Call it the STL or the stdlib, but please don't call it the STD library ;v)

Comment: Haha, oops. I have fixed my humorous mistake :)

Comment: [The STL is part of C++. I don't understand why people act like it is not.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444514/why-do-programmers-sometimes-refer-to-c-stl-like-its-a-separate-language) It was better before the edit... +1 for what it *was*.

Comment: The C++ standard library and the "STL" are not the same thing.  Certainly, parts of the SGI STL were incorporated into the C++ standard library, but it's really not at all correct to refer to the entire C++ standard library simply as the "STL."  The math library, for example, is not part of the STL but is part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: @James: does it matter? Get Herb Sutter and Scott Meyer to stop using the term "STL" incorrectly, and then I'll concede that it might be worth preaching to SO users as well. But until then, it's just a "I'm more pedantic than you" kind of showboating. The STL does not, in practical terms, if you ask a C++ programmer, refer to the SGI library, but rather to the subset of the C++ standard library that was derived from said SGI lib.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Boost doesn't *have* to use the STL at all. It's convenient to do so, but certainly not necessary. They could have used the C standard library, or even relied on OS-specific functionality and provide everything themselves.

Comment: @jalf: No, I agree with you completely; I have no objection at all to using "STL" to refer to the subset of the C++ standard library that was derived from the SGI STL. Referring to the entire C++ standard library as "the STL" is not really correct. Referring to the pieces of it that came from the SGI STL or are based on the design patterns from the STL (so, the containers, iterators, algorithms, etc.) as the "STL" is just fine, in my opinion (and I think it's good, because it provides a good, short name under which to categorize all of those related pieces of the standard library).

Comment: @James: Oh right then. :) Sorry for the misunderstanding then. :)

Comment: @jalf:  No problem :-)  (heh; I just read your quite passionate blog entry about this subject; very nice :-D)

Answer (score 1):

Boost may well use STL or other C++ standard libraries, but I think your best bet is not to be biased against that but just to try including ASIO or whatever it is you need and see if your compiled/optimized module is still small enough to meet your requirements.

You mentioned "small and fast" as if the STL wasn't small or fast, but it is pretty tight in both ways, maybe it will still meet your requirements -- it was designed to be incredibly efficient...